# How to Properly Reshape Data for ConvLSTM in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, lstm

I am trying to follow along with this tutorial [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting/) but I am running into an issue with the ConvLSTM model.

So in the tutorial they have an array, [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90] and they split it into

```
[[10,20,30]
 [20,30,40]
 [30,40,50]
 [40,50,60]
 [50,60,70]
 [60,70,80]
 [70,80,90]
```

and when they reshape it using

```
n_features = 1
n_seq = 2
n_steps = 2
X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], n_seq, n_steps, n_features))
```

it looks something like this

```
[[[10]
  [20]
  [30]]

 [[20]
  [30]
  [40]] ...
```

and my issue is that when I try to import my data and use it my data has a shape of `(133460,20)` like this

```
[[1,2,3...20]
 [1,2,3....20]]
```

the error I end up with is

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2001900 into shape (1000095,2,2,1)

and I am just a bit confused with it all and how to properly reshape my data. Here is the complete code with a note on where my code fails.

This is the tutorial code, but I don't need the `splitSequence()` function because my data is already split (same with a train/test split.

**TUTORIAL CODE**

```
# split a univariate sequence into samples
def split_sequence(sequence, n_steps):
    X, y = list(), list()
    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_steps
        # check if we are beyond the sequence
        if end_ix > len(sequence)-1:
            break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        seq_x, seq_y = sequence[i:end_ix], sequence[end_ix]
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
    return array(X), array(y)

# define input sequence
raw_seq = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
# choose a number of time steps
n_steps = 4
# split into samples
X, y = split_sequence(raw_seq, n_steps)
# reshape from [samples, timesteps] into [samples, subsequences, timesteps, features]
n_features = 1
n_seq = 2
n_steps = 2
X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], n_seq, n_steps, n_features))
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'), input_shape=(None, n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
# fit model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=500, verbose=0)
# demonstrate prediction
x_input = array([60, 70, 80, 90])
x_input = x_input.reshape((1, n_seq, n_steps, n_features))
yhat = model.predict(x_input, verbose=0)
print(yhat)
>> [[101.69263]]
```

**MY CODE**

```
# reshape from [samples, timesteps] into [samples, subsequences, timesteps, features]
n_features = 1
n_seq = 2
n_steps = 2
X = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], n_seq, n_steps, n_features)) <<<<< My code fails here
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'), input_shape=(None, n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
# fit model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=500, verbose=0)
```

pretty new to all of this so any help (especially in regards to shaping the data) would bee greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but I ran your code and it matched the results of the tutorial code. Though I was forced to replace X_train with X since X_train wasn't defined in your code. So if I had to say your problem lies with X_train, sorry I couldn't be of more help. If you clarify though what X_train is, or more specifically what makes it different from X then I can provide a more specific solution.

Comment: X train is just my data that has been split from the train/test split. So my X_train is just a smaller sub sample of my X data which is a shape of ```(133460,20)```.

in the tutorial above, their X is the array. In my code, my X_train is a different set of data with different dimensions

Comment: Oh that's the problem right there, use the tutorial's training data set.